# Javascript llamar a un método

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ext.net

tengo la siguiente parte del código:

```
 <ext:ComboBox runat="server" ID="CBO_FIL_CAJABASE" StoreID="StoreCajasBase" DisplayField="Nombre"  ValueField="Id" FieldLabel="Caja base" Flex="1">                   
                                <Triggers>
                                    <ext:FieldTrigger Icon="Clear" />
                                </Triggers>
                                <Listeners>
                                    <TriggerClick Handler="this.clearValue();CBO_FIL_VIA.clearValue();" />
                                    <Select Handler="CBO_FIL_VIA.clearValue();StoreVias.reload();" />
                                    <Change Fn="EstadoChange" />
                                </Listeners>
                            </ext:ComboBox>
```

Lo que intento conseguir es que cuando clikes en el combobox primero entre en EstadoChange, pero así no funciona sino pongo ningún valor.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que entre en esta funcion, solo al entrar dentro de un combobox?

Añado más código:

método:

```
//MMD : Validar Fecha -- > sea de un mes 
var EstadoChange = function (value) {

    var fechaInicio = document.getElementById("DTF_INICIO").value;
    var fechaFinal = document.getElementById("DTF_FIN").value;

    alert(document.getElementById("DTF_FIN").value);

    if (fechaInicio === "" || fechaFinal === "") {

        alert("inicio");

        Ext.getCmp('DTF_INICIO').allowBlank = true;
        Ext.getCmp('DTF_FIN').allowBlank = true;


    } else {

        alert("gerencia vacía");

        Ext.getCmp('DTF_INICIO').allowBlank = false;
        Ext.getCmp('DTF_FIN').allowBlank = false;
    }

};
```

Aquí os añado también todo el label panel, pero solo quiero que el método de cambiar el allowblank afecte a Gerencia.

```
 <ext:Viewport runat="server" Layout="BorderLayout">
        <Items>
            <ext:FormPanel runat="server" Region="North" Title="Criterios de selección" ButtonAlign="Center" 
                       Collapsible="true" CollapseMode="Mini" Height="120" Layout="FormLayout" Frame="true" Margins="5 5 5 5" MonitorValid="true"
                       meta:resourcekey="pnlCriterios">
                <Items>
                    <ext:CompositeField runat="server" AnchorHorizontal="100%"  FieldLabel="Gerencia" meta:resourcekey="compoGerencia">
                        <Items> <%-- MMD Gerencia no es ogligatoria. Pero fecha si lo es. Sino se pone Gerencia. --%>
                            <%-- Evolutivo V3 --%>
                            <ext:ComboBox runat="server" ID="CBO_FIL_GERENCIA" StoreID="StoreGerencias" DisplayField="Nombre"  ValueField="Id" FieldLabel="Gerencia" Flex="1">
                                 <Triggers>
                                    <ext:FieldTrigger Icon="Clear" />
                                </Triggers>
                                <Listeners>
                                    <Change Fn="EstadoChange" />
                                    <Select Handler="CBO_FIL_CAJABASE.clearValue();CBO_FIL_VIA.clearValue();StoreCajasBase.reload();" />
                                     <TriggerClick Handler="this.clearValue();CBO_FIL_VIA.clearValue();CBO_FIL_CAJABASE.clearValue();" />
                                </Listeners>
                            </ext:ComboBox>
                            <ext:Label runat="server" Text="Caja base: " LabelAlign="Right"  Margins="4 8 0 14" meta:resourcekey="lblCajaBase" />
                            <ext:ComboBox runat="server" ID="CBO_FIL_CAJABASE" StoreID="StoreCajasBase" DisplayField="Nombre"  ValueField="Id" FieldLabel="Caja base" Flex="1">                   
                                <Triggers>
                                    <ext:FieldTrigger Icon="Clear" />
                                </Triggers>
                                <Listeners>
                                    <TriggerClick Handler="this.clearValue();CBO_FIL_VIA.clearValue();" />
                                    <Select Handler="CBO_FIL_VIA.clearValue();StoreVias.reload();" />
                                </Listeners>
                            </ext:ComboBox>
                            <ext:Label runat="server" Text="Vías: " LabelAlign="Right" Margins="4 8 0 14" meta:resourcekey="lblVias" />
                            <ext:ComboBox runat="server" ID="CBO_FIL_VIA" StoreID="StoreVias" DisplayField="Codigo" ValueField="Id" Flex="1">                   
                                <Triggers>
                                    <ext:FieldTrigger Icon="Clear" />
                                </Triggers>
                                <Listeners>
                                    <TriggerClick Handler="this.clearValue();" />
                                </Listeners>
                            </ext:ComboBox>
                        </Items>
                    </ext:CompositeField>
                    <ext:CompositeField runat="server" AnchorHorizontal="100%" FieldLabel="Tipo solicitud" meta:resourcekey="compoTipo">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:ComboBox ID="CBO_TIPO_SOL" runat="server" Flex="1" Editable="false">
                                <Triggers>
                                    <ext:FieldTrigger Icon="Clear" />
                                </Triggers>
                                <Listeners>
                                    <TriggerClick Handler="this.clearValue();" />
                                </Listeners>
                            </ext:ComboBox>
                            <ext:Label runat="server" Text="Estado: " Margins="4 8 0 14" LabelAlign="Right" meta:resourcekey="lblEstado" />
                            <ext:ComboBox ID="CBO_FIL_ESTADO" runat="server" Flex="1" Editable="false">
                                <Triggers>
                                    <ext:FieldTrigger Icon="Clear" />
                                </Triggers>
                                <Listeners>
                                    <TriggerClick Handler="this.clearValue();" />
                                </Listeners>
                            </ext:ComboBox>
                            <ext:Label runat="server" Text="Albarán:" LabelAlign="Right"  Margins="4 8 0 14"/>
                            <ext:TextField MaxLength="19" ID="TXT_ALBARAN" runat="server" />
                            <ext:Label runat="server" Text="Fecha:"  LabelAlign ="Right" Margins="4 8 0 14" meta:resourcekey="lblFecha" />
                            <ext:DateField ID="DTF_INICIO" AllowBlank ="false"  runat="server" EnableKeyEvents="true" >
                              <Listeners>
                                    <Change Fn="EstadoChange" />
                                </Listeners>
                            </ext:DateField>
                            <ext:DateField ID="DTF_FIN"  AllowBlank ="false" runat="server" EnableKeyEvents="true" >
                                 <Listeners>
                                    <Change Fn="EstadoChange" />
                                </Listeners>
                            </ext:DateField>
                        </Items>
                    </ext:CompositeField>
                </Items>
                <Buttons>
                    <ext:Button runat="server" Text="Exportar" meta:resourcekey="btnExportar">
                        <Menu>
                            <ext:Menu runat="server">   
                                <Items>
                                    <ext:MenuItem runat="server" ID="BTN_EXPORT_PDF" Text="PDF" Icon="PageWhiteAcrobat" meta:resourcekey="miPDF">
                                        <DirectEvents>
                                            <Click OnEvent="ClickExportarPDF" IsUpload="true">
                                                <ExtraParams>
                                                    <ext:Parameter Name="gerencia" Value="CBO_FIL_GERENCIA.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
                                                    <ext:Parameter Name="cajabase" Value="CBO_FIL_CAJABASE.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
                                                    <ext:Parameter Name="via" Value="CBO_FIL_VIA.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
                                                    <ext:Parameter Name="tipo" Value="CBO_TIPO_SOL.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
                                                    <ext:Parameter Name="estado" Value="CBO_FIL_ESTADO.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
                                                    <ext:Parameter Name="inicio" Value="DTF_INICIO.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
                                                    <ext:Parameter Name="fin" Value="DTF_FIN.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
                                                </ExtraParams>
                                            </Click>
                                        </DirectEvents>
                                    </ext:MenuItem>
                                    <ext:MenuItem runat="server" ID="BTN_EXPORT_XLS" Text="MS. Excel" Icon="PageWhiteExcel" meta:resourcekey="miXLS">
                                        <DirectEvents>
                                            <Click OnEvent="ClickExportarXLS" IsUpload="true">
                                                <ExtraParams>
                                                    <ext:Parameter Name="gerencia" Value="CBO_FIL_GERENCIA.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
                                                    <ext:Parameter Name="cajabase" Value="CBO_FIL_CAJABASE.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
                                                    <ext:Parameter Name="via" Value="CBO_FIL_VIA.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
                                                    <ext:Parameter Name="tipo" Value="CBO_TIPO_SOL.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
                                                    <ext:Parameter Name="estado" Value="CBO_FIL_ESTADO.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
                                                    <ext:Parameter Name="inicio" Value="DTF_INICIO.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
                                                    <ext:Parameter Name="fin" Value="DTF_FIN.getValue()" Mode="Raw" />
                                                </ExtraParams>
                                            </Click>
                                        </DirectEvents>
                                    </ext:MenuItem>
                                </Items>
                            </ext:Menu>
                        </Menu>
                    </ext:Button>
                    <ext:Button runat="server" Text="Filtrar" meta:resourcekey="btnFiltrar">
                        <Listeners>
                            <Click Handler="StoreSolicitudes.reload();" />
                        </Listeners>
                    </ext:Button>
                </Buttons>
            </ext:FormPanel>
```

Gracias

Comment: En mi opinion tu código no es legible, que estas utilizando para el frontend, donde se situan tus metodos? no se entiende lo que pretendes hacer

Comment: Como comenta Enzo no queda claro qué estás intentando hacer. Ese código no tiene HTML o Javascript, es un XML que tampoco es JSP... ¿qué  librería o framework estás usando?

Comment: añado la otra parte ^^

Comment: lo que quiero conseguir es que cuando haga foco en un cuadre del combobox por ejemplo en gerencia llame al método Change, pero ahora solo lo consigo si edito la información. No solo si hago foco.

Comment: Ah, esto es .NET, verdad?

Comment: siiiii ^^ exacto! :)